# Factory method and CDI: Heavyweight instructions with assignable and execute

Tags: java, cdi, factory

I have a requirement to implement a Factory/Builder that does not know which object it has to create, so it delegates for each object to say if they are responsible for handling a parameter, this is a CDI enviroment, where Voter can have @Inject properties:

```
public interface Voter {
     boolean canVoteFor(Object);
     {ABSTAIN, GRANTED, DENIED} vote(Object)
}

public HeavyVoter implements Voter {
     @Inject
     SomeService someService1

     @Inject
     SomeService someService2

     someVeryHeavyProcessing1() { someService1() };
     someVeryHeavyProcessing2() { someVeryHeavyProcessing1(); 
               someService2();
               someOtherProcessing()}
     canVoteFor(Object) { someVeryHeavyProcessing1(); }
     {ABSTAIN, GRANTED, DENIED} vote(Object) { someVeryHeavyProcessing1(); }
}

public class VoterCounter { 
     Instance<Voter> voters;
     for (Voter voter: voters) if canVoteFor(Object) then vote(Object) ....
}
```

But I am not happy with this design because the very heavy process is repeated twice (forget about caching right now), and that stress the application.

One alternative would be to switch Voter#canVoteFor to Voter#getVoter, which returns a interface that does not use Object as parameter (the Object would be built

```
public interface VoterCreator {
    NewVoter getVoter(Object) {
}

public interface NewVoter {
     void assign(Object);
     boolean canVoteFor();
     {ABSTAIN, GRANTED, DENIED} vote()
}

public class VoterCounter { 
     Instance<VoterCreator> voters;
     for (Voter voter: voters) voter.assign(Object) ; if vote.canVoteFor() then vote() ....
}
    
}
```

However, Voter2 can only be built because of "assign(Object)". This looks like too much complexity, besides it assigns object pseudo "creation" to a method.

At the end I am confused because I need a factory, which returns objects that can have Injected properties, and stateless bean is not a good option because of the heavy processing.
.

Which would be a better design for this? J6EE environment.

Comment: Another idea is for the first case `Voter.canVoteFor(Object)` to return a "context" object that encapsulates the boolean result and any other state the voter implementation wishes to put there (simplest case could be the `Object` argument itself). Then, `Voter.vote` receives this context instead of the `Object` argument. If the context implementation, which can be specific to each voter implementation, can be trusted, there is no need to call `someVeryHeavyProcessing()` again from `vote()`.

Comment: If I didn't misunderstood you, context implementation in your example couldn't be specific for each Voter.vote , except by inheritance, right?

Comment: Yes that is probably right. I *guess* it can be worked around, if it is somehow bothering you.